Finding angle AOI in a scalene triangle
Let ABC be a scalene triangle. Let I be its incenter, and O be its circumcenter. Find $\angle{AOI}$. Click here for Diagram

I have tried constructing M the midpoint of arc BC not containing A, and I have found that $\angle{IAO}$ is $\frac{B-C}{2}$, However I am facing difficulty in finding $\angle{AOI}$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Well geometry is the most exciting n interesting thing in maths though triangles n it's centres d been my weakest point though still if u re used to a bit of trigo and aware of the fact that $OI^2 = R(R-2r)$ find the area of triangle AMO first then equate it with the sum of areas of AOI and MOI using $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$

What makes you think that it has a simple generic formula that applies to all triangles? Put another way, try to find it for some specific triangles, and see if there's some simple function relating them.

@Ash_Blanc How will you find the area of MOI ?  It will be too tedious and lengthy

@KrishivMohan area of MOI = $\frac{1}{2}R^2(R-2r)\sin{(B-C-x)}$ where $x = \angle{AOI}$


Hint: What we have are $R$ and $r$ and we can calculate d:
$d^2=R(R-2r)$
In triangle AIO we have:
$AI^2=R^2+r^2-2r\cdot R\cdot cos \theta$
For a triangle angle BAC is known , let denote it as $\widehat A$ , In triangle AIO we may write:
$AI=\frac{r}{sin \frac{\widehat A}2}$
In this way you can find $\theta$ for a certain triangle provided $R$, $r$ and $\widehat A$ is known.

This is somewhat similar to my trigonometric idea but could be less tedious (though in the both the ways, @KrishivMohan u will get two values for $\arcsin{\theta}$ $\theta$ and $\pi - \theta$

I believe it should be $2 \cdot r \cdot R \cdot \cos{\theta}$ in the second equation.

But this was still mostly helpful, thank you.

@KrishivMohan, You'r welcome. you are right, I corrected the error.
